# Postgres query optimizer generates bad plan after adding another order by criterion

Tags: postgresql

I'm using django orm with select related and it generates the query of the form:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "coupons_coupon"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "coupons_merchant"
    ON ("coupons_coupon"."merchant_id" = "coupons_merchant"."slug")
 WHERE ("coupons_coupon"."end_date" > '2020-07-10T09:10:28.101980+00:00'::timestamptz AND "coupons_coupon"."published" = true)
 ORDER BY "coupons_coupon"."end_date" ASC, "coupons_coupon"."id"
 LIMIT 5;
```

Which is then executed using the following plan:

```
Limit  (cost=4363.28..4363.30 rows=5 width=604) (actual time=21.864..21.865 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=4363.28..4373.34 rows=4022 width=604) (actual time=21.863..21.863 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: coupons_coupon.end_date, coupons_coupon.id"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2613.51..4296.48 rows=4022 width=604) (actual time=13.918..20.209 rows=4022 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((coupons_coupon.merchant_id)::text = (coupons_merchant.slug)::text)
              ->  Seq Scan on coupons_coupon  (cost=0.00..291.41 rows=4022 width=261) (actual time=0.007..1.110 rows=4022 loops=1)
                    Filter: (published AND (end_date > '2020-07-10 09:10:28.10198+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1691
              ->  Hash  (cost=1204.56..1204.56 rows=24956 width=331) (actual time=13.894..13.894 rows=23911 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 16384  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 1948kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on coupons_merchant  (cost=0.00..1204.56 rows=24956 width=331) (actual time=0.003..4.681 rows=23911 loops=1)
```

Which is a bad execution plan as join can be done after the left table has been filtered, ordered and limited. When I remove the id from order by it generates an efficient plan, which basically could have been used in the previous query as well.

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..8.84 rows=5 width=600) (actual time=0.013..0.029 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.57..6650.48 rows=4022 width=600) (actual time=0.012..0.028 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using coupons_cou_end_dat_a8d5b7_btree on coupons_coupon  (cost=0.28..1015.77 rows=4022 width=261) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=5 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (end_date > '2020-07-10 09:10:28.10198+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Filter: published
        ->  Index Scan using coupons_merchant_pkey on coupons_merchant  (cost=0.29..1.40 rows=1 width=331) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=5)
              Index Cond: ((slug)::text = (coupons_coupon.merchant_id)::text)
```

Why is this happening? Can the optimizer be nudged to use similar plan for the former query?

I'm using postgres 12.

Comment: You could change the index `coupons_cou_end_dat_a8d5b7_btree` (which presumably only contains `end_date`) to include the `id` column as well

Comment: That would probably help, but I'm still wondering why is it doing a join first and then filtering instead of the other way around.

Comment: My guess is: because the `id` column is not part of the index, the optimizer assumes that it's cheaper to first select the rows, then sort on something that isn't indexed. If you make (random) index access cheaper (`set random_page_cost = 2`), it might favor the index scan even with the order by. But unless you have a really fast harddisk (or a SSD) that might be bad for other plans

Comment: Perhaps `random_page_cost` is set too high, or `effective_cache_size` too low.

Comment: It is not clear what alternative plan you are envisioning.  A hash join does not preserve the input order of its first node except in the case that no batching is used.  And the planner cannot plan based on the assumption that no batching will be used, as to batch or not is a run time decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v13 of PostgreSQL, which should be released in the next few months, implements incremental sorting, in which it can read rows in an pre-sorted order based on prefix columns, then sorts just the ties on those prefix column(s) by the remaining column(s) in order to get a complete sort based on more columns than an index provides.  I think that will do more or less what you want.

```
Limit  (cost=2.46..2.99 rows=5 width=21)
   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=2.46..405.58 rows=3850 width=21)
         Sort Key: coupons_coupon.end_date, coupons_coupon.id
         Presorted Key: coupons_coupon.end_date
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.31..253.48 rows=3850 width=21)
               ->  Index Scan using coupons_coupon_end_date_idx on coupons_coupon  (cost=0.15..54.71 rows=302 width=17)
                     Index Cond: (end_date > '2020-07-10 05:10:28.10198-04'::timestamp with time zone)
                     Filter: published
               ->  Index Only Scan using coupons_merchant_slug_idx on coupons_merchant  (cost=0.15..0.53 rows=13 width=4)
                     Index Cond: (slug = coupons_coupon.merchant_id)
```

Of course just adding "id" into the current index will work under currently released versions, and even under version 13 is should be more efficient to have the index fully order the rows in the way you need them.